# Loading text from .txt file iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-files

I've been trying to convert a Quiz app that was based for Mac OS to iOS because I liked the idea of loading all questions from a single .txt file.

I'm still pretty new in the Objective-C language as I've used C# before.

The questions and answers are loaded via this function:

```
- (void)loadQuestionsAndAnswersArray {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Quiz1" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *textFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:NULL];

    NSArray *seperatedQA = [textFileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];

    for (NSString *QA in seperatedQA) {
        NSString *questionString = [[[QA componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Q:" withString:@""];

        NSMutableArray *answers = [[QA componentsSeparatedByString:@"A:"] mutableCopy];
        [answers removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        int correctAnswerLoc = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < answers.count; i++) {
            NSString *answer = [answers objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *editedAnswer = [answer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            editedAnswer = [editedAnswer stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                            [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            [answers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [answers insertObject:editedAnswer atIndex:i];
            answer = editedAnswer;
            if ([answer rangeOfString:@"[CORRECT]"].location != NSNotFound) {
                correctAnswerLoc = [answers indexOfObject:answer];
                NSString *editedAnswer = [answer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[CORRECT]" withString:@""];
                [answers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                [answers insertObject:editedAnswer atIndex:i];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"answers = %@", answers);

        NSDictionary *QADictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:questionString, @"question", answers, @"answers", [NSNumber numberWithInt:correctAnswerLoc], @"correctAnswerLocation", nil];

        [questionsAndAnswers addObject:QADictionary]; 
    }   

    resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[questionsAndAnswers count]];
}
```

The app then has a text field for the question and then 3 buttons, one for each answer. And when a new questions appears it changes the text within the text field and the title of the buttons.

This code works like a charm on the Mac App but on the iOS version it's like it can't find the txt file, the buttons etc is left blank.

I've been sitting on this for a week or so about now and that's the reason for this post.

The iOS app is based on this Github Mac app: https://github.com/SquaredTiki/Quizzer

If you want to have a look at how I've tried to convert the app here's a link to that to:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jqz9ue97p3v2h1/iTrafikk.zip?dl=0

And of course I'm not asking you to solve the whole issue for me, maybe just push me in the right direction if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your project. And it seems that you are not calling `loadQuestionsAndAnswersArray` anywhere in your code. Also you are not initializing the `questionsAndAnswers` anywhere in the project.

Change your code like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadQuestionsAndAnswersArray];
}

- (void)loadQuestionsAndAnswersArray
{
    NSString *filePath       = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Quiz1" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *textFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:NULL];
    NSArray *seperatedQA     = [textFileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];

    for (NSString *QA in seperatedQA)
    {
        NSString *questionString = [[[QA componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Q:" withString:@""];
        NSMutableArray *answers  = [[QA componentsSeparatedByString:@"A:"] mutableCopy];

        [answers removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        int correctAnswerLoc = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < answers.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *answer       = [answers objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *editedAnswer = [answer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            editedAnswer           = [editedAnswer stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                            [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            [answers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [answers insertObject:editedAnswer atIndex:i];
            answer = editedAnswer;
            if ([answer rangeOfString:@"[CORRECT]"].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                correctAnswerLoc       = [answers indexOfObject:answer];
                NSString *editedAnswer = [answer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[CORRECT]" withString:@""];
                [answers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                [answers insertObject:editedAnswer atIndex:i];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"answers = %@", answers);

        NSDictionary *QADictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:questionString, @"question", answers, @"answers", [NSNumber numberWithInt:correctAnswerLoc], @"correctAnswerLocation", nil];
        if (!questionsAndAnswers)
        {
            questionsAndAnswers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [questionsAndAnswers addObject:QADictionary]; 
    }   

    resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[questionsAndAnswers count]];
    [self loadQuestionsAndAnswersIntoInterface];
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! I really appreciate it! :) Finally I can continue with my project.